# PHP namespaces don't work in web hosting

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Whenever I try to use namespaces for my classes I get an error saying the class is not found or some sort, I've tried both on a free domain and a .com domain with a paid hosting. Why is that happening?...

Take for instance, I have a controllers folder and a pagesController.php function with the namespace of App\Controllers, in my autoload register I load the controllers if one is instantiated and it works fine on my local development. When I move those files to the web hosting, it'll just throw an error.

Comment: And that error is...? And your code looks like...? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Example of my usage: http://pastebin.com/rGp1deMz, I get an error saying the Database class is not found...... - [30-Jan-2017 19:32:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'classes\Database' not found in /home/pauldiamant/public_html/index.php on line 12

Comment: Did you run `composer install` on the deployed code?

Comment: I'm not even using a composer, I created my own Class with a namespace... Edit: It also seems that spl auto load isn't working on a web  host for some reason, but if I still include the file manually the namespace isn't gonna work either way.

Comment: well, could you *show* your autoload function? and your folder strucure on the server? and the installed PHP-version? (and as edit to your post, not as comment?)

Comment: There it is.. http://pastebin.com/WUX2PVkY, I'm really clueless on why it's not working with namespaces .

Comment: Is this some sort of framework?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with using namespaces... I had to use ____dir____ and then use the two dots to send it one folder back, for some reason using the 'ROOT' constant wouldn't work even though the path file was the same.

```

```
<?php

use app\classes\App as App;

require ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'functions.php';

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $validNameSpaces = [
        'app\controllers\\', 'app\models\\', 'app\classes\\'
    ];

    foreach($validNameSpaces as $namespace) {
        if(strpos($class_name, $namespace) === 0) {
            $path = __DIR__ . '/../' . strtr($class_name, '\\', '/') . '.php';
            if(is_file($path) && is_readable($path)) {
                include_once $path;

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});

App::instance();

include_once "routes.php";
```

```